# "Le lion mange durant la nuit" ou "le lion mange à la nuit" ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, indications-de-temps

Comment puis-je dire:

> le lion mange durant la nuit
>
> le lion mange à la nuit

ou est-ce que il y a autre manière?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to state a general fact like this

> Le lion mange la nuit.

Of course it doesn't mean that the night gets eaten.

You can also use *pendant* or as you suggested *durant*, but the latter adds emphasis on the time span, which is probably not what was intended here. So the most natural phrasing with a preposition is the following:

> Le lion mange pendant la nuit.

Comment: You may also say "Le lion mange à la nuit tombée", even if the meaning is different

Comment: This answer forgets half the question : Using "à la nuit" means that the Lion eats as the night comes. It's a shortening of @Random 's version.

Comment: @MakorDal: *à la nuit* alone is simply incorrect, *à* can only introduce a sufficiently precise moment, e.g. *à la nuit tombée*, *au petit matin*, *à l'aube*, *à 3h*, etc.

Comment: Yet still used, both in literature for poetic license and colloquially. "À la brune", if you want.